# How to return after restarting python?

Tags: python, return-value, restart

Here is code:

```
def test():
    //restarting python
    os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
print("Successfull")
return("Succesfull")
```

It's restarting python but not returning or printing value.

Comment: `return` and `print` should be inside the function

Comment: You never call `test()`. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I have a function called restart() inside the class and i need to restart the python and retiurn status code as 200 and print "successfull" msg.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your indentation is not correct so please have look at beloow code:

```
def test():
    try:
        print("Successfull")
        return("Succesfull")
    except Exception:
        #do something
    finally:
        os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)


test()
```

> **Note:** The **`finally`** statement will be executed even if an exception was caught.

Comment: How can i return "succesull" before executing os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)

Comment: @rts Why would you even want to return "successful" *before* runing `execv`?